# How to fail CMake gracefully when an include file does not exist?

Tags: c, cmake

In CMakeLists.txt, I would like to check that bzlib.h exists:

```
include(CheckIncludeFiles)
check_include_file(bzlib.h HAVE_BZLIB_H)
if(NOT HAVE_BZLIB_H)
    # How can I exit cmake with an error message if bzlib.h does not exists?
endif()
```

Comment: You should fix the `if`, change it to `if(NOT HAVE_BZLIB_H)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's quite easy:
`message( FATAL_ERROR "Your message" )`