# Right way to check include files in CMAKE

Tags: cmake

I  used this way of detecting include files, but the error if it's not detected is never executed:

```
include(CheckIncludeFile)
check_include_file("getopt.h" HAVE_GETOPT_H)
if(!HAVE_GETOPT_H)
  message( FATAL_ERROR "getopt Not Found" )
endif()
```

But If I check with empty String is working, and the message is printed when include files is not found:

```
include(CheckIncludeFile)
check_include_file("getopt.h" HAVE_GETOPT_H)
if("${HAVE_GETOPT_H}" STREQUAL "")
  message( FATAL_ERROR "getopt Not Found" )
endif()
```

am I doing something wrong? I'm using cmake version 2.8.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake's [`if`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aif) command negates the argument by using `NOT` rather than `!`.

You need to do:

```
if(NOT HAVE_GETOPT_H)
```

Comment: I'm using this (apparently wrong) example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674678/how-to-fail-cmake-gracefully-when-an-include-file-does-not-exist